# Show that if $\operatorname{trace}(AB) = 0$ and $\operatorname{rank} (A)=1$ then $ABA=0$

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank, trace

I know that

$$AB-BA=A \iff A \text{ is singular}$$

$A$ and $B$ can be complex. Any hints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Since $A$ has rank $1$, we can write
$$A = \mathbf{u}\mathbf{v}^\mathrm{T}$$
for some vectors $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$. Now use the cyclicity of the trace with respect to its arguments and see what you get with $\mathrm{Tr}(AB)=0$.

Comment: What do you mean by trace cyclicity?

Comment: I mean that the trace is invariant with respect to cyclic permutations of its argument. For example, $\mathrm{Tr}(ABC) = \mathrm{Tr}(BCA) = \mathrm{Tr}(CAB)$.

Comment: @PanthersFan92 Cyclicity refers to the fact that $\operatorname{tr}(AB)=\operatorname{tr}(BA)$, which implies that you can cyclically permute the entries in trace (though it does not imply that you can take arbitrary permutations like yo1u generally can with determinants of products of square matrices).  So $\operatorname{tr}(ABC)=\operatorname{tr}(BCA)$, but in general $\operatorname{tr}(ABC)\neq \operatorname{tr}(BAC)$ even if both products are well defined.

Comment: I know that $\operatorname{trace}(AB)=\operatorname{trace}(BA)$ already, but I don't undertand:
1. What does that have to do with $A=uv^T$
2. How does that prove that ABA=0 (i'm talking about matrix multiplication here)

Comment: Rank one means that you can think of every row of $A$ as a constant multiple of its first row. Just a thought.

Comment: @PanthersFan92 Both $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}^\mathrm{T}$ are matrices as well, so they can be cyclically permuted within the trace. Then you get $$\mathrm{Tr}(AB) = \mathrm{Tr}(\mathbf{u}\mathbf{v}^\mathrm{T}B) = \mathrm{Tr}(\mathbf{v}^\mathrm{T}B\mathbf{u}).$$ But the latter is just a scalar, and the trace of a scalar is just itself. So this argument shows that $0 = \mathbf{v}^\mathrm{T}B\mathbf{u}$. This should be helpful in proving $ABA = 0$.

Comment: But aren't $u$ and $v^T$ vectors? they aren't square matrices, so does the cyclic property still relevant?

Comment: They are many objects at once, and part of linear algebra is learning the relations between them. For example, a row vector can be thought of as a vector (an element of a vector space), a linear functional (something that takes a vector to a number), a $1\times n$ matrix, and so on. The cyclicity property holds for arbitrary sized matrices, as long as the multiplication makes sense. The matrix $B$ doesn't have to be square either, but both $AB$ and $BA$ have to be square for the cyclic property to make sense. Say $B$ were $m\times n$. Then $A$ would have to be $n\times m$.

Comment: So then $\mathbf{u}$ would be a $n \times 1$ matrix, and $\mathbf{v}^\mathrm{T}$ would be a $1\times m$ matrix. The product $\mathbf{u}\mathbf{v}^\mathrm{T}B$ would be $n\times n$, the product $\mathbf{v}^\mathrm{T}B\mathbf{u}$ would be $1\times 1$ (scalar) and the product $B\mathbf{u}\mathbf{v}^\mathrm{T}$ would be $m\times m$. Each of these are different sized square matrices, and the trace makes sense for each of these matrices, and the cyclic property guarantees that the traces are in fact equal.

Answer (score 5):

Since $\operatorname{rank} (\mathrm A) = 1$, there are vectors $\mathrm{u}, \mathrm{v} \in \mathbb{C}^n$ such that $\mathrm A = \mathrm{u} \mathrm{v}^*$. Hence,

$$\operatorname{tr} (\mathrm A \mathrm B) = \operatorname{tr} (\mathrm{u} \mathrm{v}^* \mathrm B) = \operatorname{tr} (\mathrm{v}^* \mathrm B \mathrm{u}) = \mathrm{v}^* \mathrm B \mathrm{u}$$

If $\operatorname{tr} (\mathrm A \mathrm B) = 0$, then $\mathrm{v}^* \mathrm B \mathrm{u} = 0$. Thus,

$$\mathrm A \mathrm B \mathrm A = \mathrm{u} \mathrm{v}^* \mathrm B \mathrm{u} \mathrm{v}^* = \mathrm{u} (\underbrace{\mathrm{v}^* \mathrm B \mathrm{u}}_{=0}) \mathrm{v}^* = 0 \cdot \mathrm A = \mathrm O_n$$

---

[linear-algebra](/questions/tagged/linear-algebra) [matrices](/questions/tagged/matrices) [rank-1-matrices](/questions/tagged/rank-1-matrices) [trace](/questions/tagged/trace)

Answer (score 1):

The cyclicity of the trace is certainly the way to go here, however, I'll offer a solution that is more basic although a bit brute force. I'm  going to assume real entries, but the calculation is nearly identical if complex entries are allowed.

Since $n\times m$ matrix $A$ is rank one, it's rows can be written as multiples of a single row vector.

$$
A=
\left[\begin{matrix}
a_1r_1 & a_1r_2 & \cdots & a_1r_m \\
a_2r_1 & a_2r_2 & \cdots & a_2r_m \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_nr_1 & a_nr_2 & \cdots & a_nr_m \\
\end{matrix}\right]=
\left[\begin{matrix}
a_1 \\
a_2  \\
\vdots\\
a_n  \\
\end{matrix}\right]
\left[\begin{matrix}
r_1 \ \ r_2  \ \ \cdots \ \ r_m 
\end{matrix}\right]=\mathbf{a} \mathbf{r}^T .
$$

Let $m\times n$ matrix $B=[b_{ij}],$ and let $\mathbf{b}_i$ be the $i^{th}$ column of matrix $B$. Let's take a look at the product $AB.$

$$
\begin{aligned}
AB
=\mathbf{a} \mathbf{r}^T B
&=\left[\begin{matrix}
a_1 \\
a_2  \\
\vdots\\
a_n  \\
\end{matrix}\right]
\left[\begin{matrix}
r_1 \ \ r_2  \ \ \cdots \ \ r_m 
\end{matrix}\right]
\left[\begin{matrix}
\mathbf{b}_1 \ \ \mathbf{b}_2  \ \ \cdots \ \ \mathbf{b}_n 
\end{matrix}\right] \\
&=\left[\begin{matrix}
a_1\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{b}_1 & a_1\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{b}_2 & \cdots & a_1\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{b}_n \\
a_2\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{b}_1 & a_2\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{b}_2 & \cdots & a_2\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{b}_n \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_n\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{b}_1 & a_n\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{b}_2 & \cdots & a_n\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{b}_n \\
\end{matrix}\right].
\end{aligned}
$$

Now we know that Tr$(AB)=0$ so that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{b}_k = 0.
$$

Now let's look at $AB\mathbf{a}$ and conclude that it is a zero column vector. The $i^{th}$ component is:

$$
\begin{aligned}
(AB\mathbf{a})_i&=
\left[\begin{matrix}
a_i\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{b}_1 & a_i\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{b}_2 & \cdots & a_i\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{b}_n
\end{matrix}\right]
\left[\begin{matrix}
a_1 \\
a_2  \\
\vdots\\
a_n  \\
\end{matrix}\right] \\
&=a_i\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{b}_k = 0.
\end{aligned}
$$

So not only do we have $ABA=\mathbf{a}\mathbf{r}^TB\mathbf{a}\mathbf{r}^T=O_n$ (the $n\times n$ zero matrix), we also have that $\mathbf{a}\mathbf{r}^TB\mathbf{a}=\mathbf{0}_n$ (the $n\times 1$ zero column vector). Likewise, we can show that $\mathbf{r}^TB\mathbf{a}\mathbf{r}^T=\mathbf{0}_m^T$ (the $1\times m$ zero row vector). And of course as noted in the other answers, $\mathbf{r}^TB\mathbf{a}=0$ (the number zero).